# How to update data from child component to parent component using context api in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management, react-context

I have two components app.js and posts.js.

My app.js component

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'
import Posts from './components/Posts'

const val = createContext()

const App = () => {
  const msg = 'hi'

  return (
    <div>
      <val.Provider value={msg}>
        <Posts />
      </val.Provider>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
export { val }
```

My Posts.js component

```
import React from 'react'
import { val } from '../App'
import { useContext } from 'react'

const Posts = () => {
  const greet = useContext(val)
  return <div>{greet}</div>
}

export default Posts
```

I want to update the msg from 'hi' to let say 'hello' from Posts component but I don't know how it can be done can someone plz help me understand that including the flow of how values get changed ? I
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msg` needs to be state:

```
const App = () => {
  const state = useState('hi')

  return (
    <div>
      <val.Provider value={state}>
        <Posts />
      </val.Provider>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and then:

```
const Posts = () => {
  const [greet,setGreet] = useContext(val)
  return (
    <>
      <div>{greet}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setGreet('hello')}>Change to hello</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

It's helpful to look at context as just a prop from far above that you don't want to keep passing down. It's helpful, because that's all that it is.

A reason to use context instead of a prop:

You've got to pass it down through a lot of components, some of which really don't have anything to do with that prop

A reason **not** to use context:

You're tightly coupling your component to that context.

It's up to you to decide if the tradeoffs of tight coupling are worth it. Sometimes they are, sometimes they aren't. No hard and fast rules.

Comment: Hey can you explain me how reducer and action comes into play ? I had gone through lots of resources bt coudn't understood that ?

Comment: You don't have a reducer or action in your code. I'm guessing you're talking about `useReducer`, though?

Comment: yes i had seen in many tutorial they use reducer action dispatch along with context what's the significance of them using together could you plz explain me the flow ? Thanks.

Comment: useReducer is just another (redux-style) way to manage state. It's like useState+1. I've honestly never needed to use useReducer because `useState` wouldn't work (and I've written a lot of react). For all intents and purposes, when it comes to context, there's no difference - context usually provides a value that is usually state (whether that state comes from useReducer or useState doesn't matter) and an updater (like dispatch from useReducer, or the `setX` from useState). That's all you need to know.

Comment: For me **setGreet** is undefined.

Comment: @PawelWujczyk check your code, make sure you’re not using two curly braces like `value={{state}}`.